# drag drop div multiple select fail on combined demo

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, resize

I am creating a div and place a new div inside that i can drag around using;
http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag#demos

I combined the following demo's:

- contain
- active
- multi
- live (dynamically add new divs)
- resize2

I can dynamically add new divs to the contained space, this div is also re-sizable and movable.
The problem is that it behaves weird.
- after clicking add, you cannot instantly drag that new box.
- multiple select does not work for all items
- I've had a situation where multiple select 3 items, but i can't un-select them.

here the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/GVNv5/2/

scenario 1: dragging
the 3 boxes are stacked on top of each-other ( no problem here)
- try dragging the top box immediately (without clicking it first) you see it doesn't move.  Let go of your mouse and try again, now it will move. (the second and third boxes will move also)
- click add a box button and try to move it immediately, it also doesn't move.(the second time it will)
- click a box to select it.(color red) You will see non of the boxes will get selected.

scenario 2: multiselect
Run the demo again
- click on a box to select it.(color red) It will not select on first click. (hold mouse still)
- click on box and drag mouse, now release mouse.. box is selected.
- select box 1 and 2
- create new box and select it
- now you cannot un-select box 1 and 2.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://threedubmedia.com/inc/js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://threedubmedia.com/inc/js/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://threedubmedia.com/inc/js/jquery.event.drag.live-2.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
            <style type="text/css">
    .drag {
        font-size:8px;
        position: absolute;
        border: 1px solid #89B;
        /*background: #BCE;*/
        background: rgba(212, 217, 240, .8);
        height: 58px;
        width: 58px;
        cursor: move;
        }
    #map_container {
        height: 299px;
        width:50%;
        border: 1px dashed #888;
        }



    .handle {
        position: absolute;
        height: 6px;
        width: 6px;
        border: 1px solid #89B;
        background: #9AC; 
        }
    .NW, .NN, .NE {
        top: -4px;
        }
    .NE, .EE, .SE {
        right: -4px;
        }
    .SW, .SS, .SE {
        bottom: -4px;
        }
    .NW, .WW, .SW {
        left: -4px;
        }
    .SE, .NW {  
        cursor: nw-resize;
        }
    .SW, .NE {
        cursor: ne-resize;
        }
    .NN, .SS {
        cursor: n-resize;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -4px;
        }
    .EE, .WW {
        cursor: e-resize;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -4px;
        }   
    .selected {
        background-color: #ECB;
        border-color: #B98;
        }
    .selected .handle {  
        background-color: #CA9;
        border-color: #B98;
        }

    .active {
        background-color: #BEE;
        border-color: #8BB;
        }
        </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        var $div = $('#map_container');



        //----------------------------------------------------------
        // adding new div to drag
        //----------------------------------------------------------
        var num = 1;
            $('#add').click(function(){
            num++;
                $('<div class="drag">'+num+
                    '<div class="handle NE"></div>'+
                    '<div class="handle NN"></div>'+
                    '<div class="handle NW"></div>'+
                    '<div class="handle WW"></div>'+
                    '<div class="handle EE"></div>'+
                    '<div class="handle SW"></div>'+
                    '<div class="handle SS"></div>'+
                    '<div class="handle SE"></div>'+
                    '</div>')
                    .appendTo( $div )
            });
    //----------------------------------------------------------
    //dragging and resizing //----------------------------------------------------------    
        $( document ).on("drag",function(){
         $('.drag')
        .click(function(){
            $( this ).toggleClass("selected");
        })
        .drag("init",function(){
            if ( $( this ).is('.selected') )
                return $('.selected');
        })

        .drag("start",function( ev, dd ){
            dd.attr = $( ev.target ).prop("className");
            $( this ).addClass("active");
            //console.log(dd.attr);//to log some stuff to the console (you could use firefox firebug to see)
            dd.limit = $div.offset();
            dd.limit.bottom = dd.limit.top + $div.outerHeight() - $( this ).outerHeight();
            dd.limit.right = dd.limit.left + $div.outerWidth() - $( this ).outerWidth();
            dd.width = $(this).width();
            dd.height = $(this).height();
        })
        .drag(function( ev, dd ){

                var props = {};

                if ( dd.attr.indexOf("E") > -1 ){
                    props.width = Math.max( 32, dd.width + dd.deltaX );
                }
                if ( dd.attr.indexOf("S") > -1 ){
                    props.height = Math.max( 32, dd.height + dd.deltaY );
                }
                if ( dd.attr.indexOf("W") > -1 ){
                    props.width = Math.max( 32, dd.width - dd.deltaX );
                    props.left = dd.originalX + dd.width - props.width;
                }
                if ( dd.attr.indexOf("N") > -1 ){
                    props.height = Math.max( 32, dd.height - dd.deltaY );
                    props.top = dd.originalY + dd.height - props.height;
                }

                var props2 = {};
                if ( dd.attr.indexOf("drag") > -1 )
                {
                    props2.top =Math.min( dd.limit.bottom, Math.max( dd.limit.top, dd.offsetY ) );
                    props2.left =Math.min( dd.limit.right, Math.max( dd.limit.left, dd.offsetX ) );
                }           
                $( this ).css( props2 );

            if(dd.attr == 'drag')
            {
                //you can do stuff here if needed
            }
            else if(dd.attr == 'handle NE' || dd.attr == 'handle NN' || dd.attr == 'handle NW' || dd.attr == 'handle WW' || dd.attr == 'handle EE' || dd.attr == 'handle SW' || dd.attr == 'handle SS' || dd.attr == 'handle SE')
            {
                $( this ).css( props ); 
            }       
        })
        .drag("end",function(){
                $( this ).removeClass("active");                           
            });

        });
    });
    </script>


    <input type="button" id="add" value="Add a Box" />
    <div id="map_container">
    <div class="drag">
        <div class="handle NE"></div>
        <div class="handle NN"></div>
        <div class="handle NW"></div>
        <div class="handle WW"></div>
        <div class="handle EE"></div>
        <div class="handle SW"></div>
        <div class="handle SS"></div>
        <div class="handle SE"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="drag">
        <div class="handle NE"></div>
        <div class="handle NN"></div>
        <div class="handle NW"></div>
        <div class="handle WW"></div>
        <div class="handle EE"></div>
        <div class="handle SW"></div>
        <div class="handle SS"></div>
        <div class="handle SE"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="drag">
        <div class="handle NE"></div>
        <div class="handle NN"></div>
        <div class="handle NW"></div>
        <div class="handle WW"></div>
        <div class="handle EE"></div>
        <div class="handle SW"></div>
        <div class="handle SS"></div>
        <div class="handle SE"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also having Same Problem...

Answer (score 1):

i think you must use

```
$(document).on('click')
```

instead of using

```
$(document).on('drag')
```

because drag will not fire on 1st action..

check out here i have done it: http://jsfiddle.net/CD3fb/